# rtw.codemetrics.C_CodeMetrics' contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by another file with the same name

Tags: matlab, exe

I am deploying my project using deploytool in MATLAB. I added few function files with main.m file and run the build. It stoped on build failed and return an error:

> rtw.codemetrics.C_CodeMetrics' contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by another file with the same name.

Please help ....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to run your code fine?

Comment: Yes...its working fine from Matlab command window.

Comment: I installed the new version than the version on which I was trying to deploy my project. now its done successfully......